# how can i get logs of all the pods in my project as an openshift non-admin user?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, fluentd, paas, okd

I want to create a helm chart for my users who wants to deploy there own logging stack in my PaaS, my api is pretty much exactly the same as openshift api, but i don't know how a user can deploy fluentd in there project and get all the logs of all the pods inside of that project.

Answer (score 1):

To get the logs of all the pods inside a project, one could use a bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for p in $(oc get pods -n $1 | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | tail -n +2); do
    oc logs $p
done
```

1. Save the code as `pods-all-ns.sh`
2. Run the bash script using the command line providing the project name `./pods-all-ns.sh default`

To get all the logs of all the pods of a deployment, one could a label selector `oc logs -l service=logevents`